Is there a way I can use the `exclude` argument in `library()` on a sub-package?
I keep on running into this issue, where purrr::invoke is masking sparklyr::invoke.  It causes a lot of {sparklyr} functionalities not to work.
I can fix it with invoke <- sparklyr::invoke, but it seems like a hack.  Is there a way to use the exclude argument in library() instead?
I tried both of these, and neither worked.
library(tidyverse, exclude = "invoke")
#> Warning in rm(list = exclude, envir = env): object 'invoke' not found
invoke
#> function (.f, .x = NULL, ..., .env = NULL) 
#> {
#>     lifecycle::deprecate_soft("1.0.0", "invoke()", "exec()")
#>     .env <- .env %||% parent.frame()
#>     args <- c(as.list(.x), list(...))
#>     do.call(.f, args, envir = .env)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000001a77b6339f0>
#> <environment: namespace:purrr>

library(tidyverse, exclude = "purrr::invoke")
#> Warning in rm(list = exclude, envir = env): object 'purrr::invoke' not found
invoke
#> function (.f, .x = NULL, ..., .env = NULL) 
#> {
#>     lifecycle::deprecate_soft("1.0.0", "invoke()", "exec()")
#>     .env <- .env %||% parent.frame()
#>     args <- c(as.list(.x), list(...))
#>     do.call(.f, args, envir = .env)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000001c03be31e78>
#> <environment: namespace:purrr>


I don't know the answer to this and I think it's an interesting question in the general sense. But in this case specifically wouldn't it be easier just explicitly call purrr::invoke(), or if you are determined not to do that, just load purrr directly, and any other tidyverse packages you need? Always seems to me that library(tidyverse) is asking for problems like this.

You can use the conflicted package to handle this.  Either of these will give you sparklyr::invoke when you ask for invoke:
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr)
conflicted::conflict_prefer("invoke", "sparklyr")

or loading in the other order:
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)
conflicted::conflict_prefer("invoke", "sparklyr")


1) Personally I prefer to use library with the individual packages underlying tidyverse rather than with tidyverse itself in which case there is no problem in using exclude= but if you want to use library(tidyverse) anyways then do it like this:
library(purrr, exclude = "invoke")
library(tidyverse)

# test
invoke
## Error: object 'invoke' not found

2) Another approach is to just issue the library call to sparklyr after the one to tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr)
invoke
## function (jobj, method, ...) 
## {
##     invoke_trace(spark_connection(jobj), "Invoking", method)
##     UseMethod("invoke")
## }
## <bytecode: 0x000001ebb8bb14a0>
## <environment: namespace:sparklyr>
 

